# jQuery isotope: IE not loading

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

This is a common problem on a browser I never use, but it seems some still do. When I set up an isotope grid on sites, they seem to work fine in every browser, but when I come to test in IE using http://netrenderer.com it fails to lay out the divs and instead they're all stuck to the left of the browser. I'm trying to find a jQuery method to initiate isotope / masonry layouts etc that is cross browser friendly (IE especially).
Here's a simple mockup in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/73Xv7/3/

and the live demo version too: http://jsfiddle.net/73Xv7/3/show/

jQuery:

```
var jQuerycontainer = jQuery('#main-grid');

jQuerycontainer.imagesLoaded( function(){
jQuerycontainer.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-block',
    animationEngine: 'best-available',
    masonry: {
    columnWidth: 4
    }
});
    });
```

Something else I tried was setting the body to `display: none` and initiating a fadeIn on the window load like so:

```
(function($) {

  $(window).load(function() {
    $(document.body).fadeIn(1000);
  });

  setTimeout(function() {
      $('#main-grid').isotope( 'reLayout' );
}, 1000);

})(jQuery);
```

With the aim of giving the scripts more time to load, again this works in all browsers, bar IE. Is there any method to initiate masonry layouts that would work in IE too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried your jsfiddle in IE8 and IE9 and it is working. I think it might be a problem with netrenderer.com engine.

Have you considered using the layout callback function to trigger the fadeIn?

```
$('#container').isotope({
  onLayout: function( $elems, instance ) {
    // `this` refers to jQuery object of the container element
    console.log( this.height() );
    // callback provides jQuery object of laid-out item elements
    $elems.css({ background: 'blue' });
    // instance is the Isotope instance
    console.log( instance.$filteredAtoms.length );
  }
});
```

see: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html

Comment: I tried this on both the "netrenderer" and on IE 9. Pretty sure its netrenderer issue. I can't even get it to display http://jsfiddle.net